# Why is this calling the copy constructor so many times?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class that resembles this:

However, after the initial constructor, the copy constructor is being called 10 times.
If I don't do the thread creation step.  It gets called 4 times which is what I'd expect.
Why is that, and how do I avoid it?

Should I avoid using std::vector in this case and just do new delete instead?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

class A
{
    public:
        A() { printf("hello\n"); }
        ~A() { printf("Goodbye\n"); }
        A(const A&)
        {
            printf("copy constructing\n");
        }

        Thread() { }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a(4, A);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        threads_.create_thread(boost::bind(&A::Thread, a[i]));
    }
}
```

Ok, I found the problem.

This:

```
        threads_.create_thread(boost::bind(&A::Thread, a[i]));
```

Should be:

```
        threads_.create_thread(boost::bind(&A::Thread, &a[i]));
```

Comment: Are you overlapping code from your previous question ??

Comment: Yes but it's a different problem.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid copies? Why aren't you focusing on getting your programs working cleanly?

Comment: Exactly GMan.  All I can say is that the moment I put the & in bind it worked properly.  I think it's the way my ctor is defined and the fact that some members are non-copyable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Boost.Ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/ref.html)

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
     threads_.create_thread(boost::bind(&A::Thread, boost::ref(a[i]) ));
}
```

this is from the  [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html) :

> The arguments that bind takes are
>   copied and held internally by the
>   returned function object. For example,
>   in the following code:
>
> int i = 5;
>
> bind(f, i, _1);
>
> a copy of the value of i is stored
>   into the function object. boost::ref
>   and boost::cref can be used to make
>   the function object store a reference
>   to an object, rather than a copy:
>
> int i = 5;
>
> bind(f, ref(i), _1);
>
> bind(f, cref(42), _1);

Answer (score 1):

Threads are irrelevant here. The "problem" is with `boost::bind`; it makes copies of the arguments you give it, so it can use the value later when invoked. [Use `ref`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133385/why-is-this-calling-the-copy-constructor-so-many-times/4133486#4133486) so have it store a reference instead.

> Should I avoid using std::vector in this case and just do new delete instead?

Huh? Why would you do that? You need to get over the fact copies are made; that just happens. You should be worried about writing clean, maintainable code first, not whether or not you happen to make a copy. There's no reason to use `new[]` over a `std::vector`; **never** use `delete`.